# Cache: expire data when table data changes

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching

Is it a way to store data in Cache on Client side and expire data from cache only when rows from two tables are updated/inserted? I need to load menu with the right permissions from the database only when a permission is changes. On the current implementation, the menu items are loaded from database in a TreeView every time the page loads.

So is there a straight way to accomplish this? Because I can't use `Sliding Expiration` and `Absolute Expiration` because I don't know when the Admin will change the user rights.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there's a way to do this. It's called SQL Cache Dependecy and the whole technique is rather involved. [Take a look at this very detailed tutorial.](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/data-access/caching-data/using-sql-cache-dependencies-cs)

[Here's another](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/showarticle.aspx?ID=263) fairly good tutorial on the same topic.